# How can I remove the last character of a String in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, string, substring, swift4

How do I remove the last character of a string in Swift 4? I used to use `substring` in earlier versions of Swift, but the `substring` method is deprecated.

Here's the code I have.

```
temp = temp.substring(to: temp.index(before: temp.endIndex))
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`dropLast()` is your safest bet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47317030/3151675), because it handles nils and empty strings without crashing [(answer by OverD)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47317030/3151675), but if you want to return the character you removed, use `removeLast()`:

```
var str = "String"
let removedCharacter = str.removeLast() //str becomes "Strin"
                                        //and removedCharacter will be "g"
```

A *different* function, `removeLast(_:)` changes the count of the characters that should be removed:

```
var str = "String"
str.removeLast(3) //Str
```

The difference between the two is that `removeLast()` **returns** the character that was removed, while `removeLast(_:)` does not have a return value:

```
var str = "String"
print(str.removeLast()) //prints out "g"
```

Comment: This answer should be posted to the duplicate question instead of this question.

Comment: Note that it would crash if the string is empty

Comment: I would recommend `dropLast` instead, which returns an empty `Substring` when applied to an empty `String`, rather than crashing.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `dropLast()`

You can find more information on [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689669-droplast)

Comment: This is the safest approach

Comment: No crash with `nil`, `empty` & `""` Working well.

Answer (score 2):

A literal Swift 4 conversion of your code is

```
temp = String(temp[..<temp.index(before: temp.endIndex)])
```

- `foo.substring(from: index)` becomes `foo[index...]`
- `foo.substring(to: index)` becomes `foo[..<index]`

  and in particular cases a new `String` must be created from the `Substring` result.

but the solution in the4kmen's answer is much better.

Comment: This would also crash if the string is empty

Comment: Indeed, as well as the expression in the question.